# What countries Indian passport holders can travel without a visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, vacations

What countries Indian passport holders can travel to without a visa and how many days they can stay ?

I have put some of them, here is the list:
- Hong Kong, 15 days
- Bhutan, how many days?
- Jamaica, is it 60 days or 120 Days?
- Other countries ?

Comment: Does that include visa on arrival and eVisas ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in phoog's answer, the ultimate authoritative answer for such matters is always the destination country's official government publications.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens) has a list of visa requirements for each country for Indian passport holders. Here's the list current Jan 2016, not including visa on arrival and eVisas, and excluding the host of other small territories such as Réunion or Montserrat that don't require visas.

- Bhutan
- Dominica (6 months)
- Ecuador (90 days)
- El Salvador (90 days)
- Fiji (4 months)
- Grenada (3 months)
- Haiti (3 months)
- Indonesia (30 days)
- Jamaica
- Mauritius (90 days)
- Micronesia (30 days)
- Nepal
- Saint Kitts and Nevis (3 months)
- Saint Vincent and the Grenadines (1 month)
- Senegal (90 days)
- Trinidad (90 days)
- Vanuatu (30 days)

Comment: It's worth noting that the Wikipedia page is much more likely to be updated to reflect changes than is this answer.

Comment: @phoog sure but the list isn't that long and countries don't change their visa requirements every day. I didn't want to provide nothing but a link

Comment: Of course.  I'm just thinking of someone reading this in 5 or 10 years, who ought to visit the Wikipedia page.  In any case, anyone planning to travel should check with the authorities of the countries they plan to visit.  Come to think of it, I will offer that as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens) page for visa requirements for any citizenship.
For the official countries, you can go to :

Bhutan
Dominica
Ecuador
El Salvador
Fiji
Grenada
Haiti
Indonesia
Jamaica
Mauritius
Micronesia
Nepal
Saint Kitts and Nevis
Senegal
Trinidad and Tobago
Vanuatu

There is many exceptions though (e-visas, visa on arrival, organized trips) that make it possible to go to other countries without a visa. All is explained in the wikipedia page (to be sure also check the sources for each information).

Answer (score 0):

Any list of visa requirements for citizens of a given country is of limited value to someone who is actually planning to travel.  Countries change these requirements from time to time, so whenever anyone travels they should confirm visa requirements with the authorities of each country they plan to visit.

Editable lists, such as those on Wikipedia, are more likely to be accurate, but even so, anyone who relies on such a list is at the mercy of strangers.  After any such change, the list will probably be brought up to date eventually, but someone investing in an international trip probably wants more certainty than "probably" and "eventually."